# UIBlurEffect doesn't affect on UIView behind it

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview

This is how I define `UIVisualEffectView`:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.addSubview(self)

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 300, 50)
    blurEffectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

But this is a result:

[image]

but as you can see, the title of navigationBar is not blurred at all. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`superview` of `blurEffectView` must have:

```
alpha = 1
backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```